# adding barriers is not working in arcgis sdk for android

Tags: android, arcgis-android

I have a program that displays this path when I give it two points shown by the red marker.

[image]

I wanted to create a barrier on that road so I added this code

```js
        Polygon po=new Polygon();
        Point p1=new Point(4102363.9071817156,857772.619643);
        Point p2=new Point(4102416.5557467686,857799.2401230272);
        Point p3=new Point(4102436.1589281,857744.31787604);
        po.startPath(p1);
        po.lineTo(p2);
        po.lineTo(p3);
        Graphic ba_gr=new Graphic(po,null);
        NAFeaturesAsFeature na=new NAFeaturesAsFeature();
        na.addFeature(ba_gr);
        params.setPolygonBarriers(na);
```

**params** is my **RouteParameters**

On my previous code but my program still shows be the previous path. Did I miss something when creating the barriers?

The polygon is in this position,

[image]

I tried it on another program.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was i was not setting the barrier spatial reference the same as the map's spatial reference